# COM interop question

Tags: c#, com, interop

Am using COM interop in my C# application.

I've this line of code:

```
IMyInterface objData = MyCOMClass.GetData();
```

My question here is:

Do I need to release resources on objData by using?
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(objData);

Thanks for reading.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to clean up a COM object in a .net application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3650878/best-way-to-clean-up-a-com-object-in-a-net-application)

Comment: In this question, I wanted to know if an object of type "interface"[as against class] would need to get cleaned up as well using ReleaseComObject.Hence I posted a new question.Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, unless it is ok for you to wait until the GC cleans it up.

Could be worth noting that the COM interop creates one COM reference per Interface.

```
IMyInterface x = MyCOMClass.GetData();
IMyOtherInterface y = (IMyOtherInterface)x;
IMyInterface z = x;

Marshal.ReleaseComObject(x);
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(y);
```

or
    Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(x); // If you know nobody else uses it

Comment: Thanks adrianm for your response.This helps.